# How do I convert a `matrix` in one form to a `matrix` in another form (like `bmatrix` environment)

Tags: keyboard-macros, calc, math

I'm attempting to take faster linear algebra notes within org-mode. The latex of a matrix is complex to write, so I'm trying to develop a shorthand expansion.

My current workflow is to highlight a shorthand and run `M-x latex-matrixify`. Unfortunately, it seems to complain:

```
let: Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)
```

I believe because I'm adding things into the region that's selected, the bounds are not being updated to contain all of the new information.

Here's the current code:

```lisp
(defun latex-matrixify ()
  "turn a shorthand matrix of [2,3,4|2\\9,2,1|9] into the proper latex form"
  (interactive)
  (if (not (use-region-p))
      (message "You have to select a region to operate on.")
    (let ((pairs (list
                  (cons "]" "\\end{bmatrix}")
                  (cons "[" "\\begin{bmatrix}")
                  (cons "," " & ")
                  (cons "\\" "\\
")
                  (cons "|" " & | &")
                        )))
      (dolist (p pairs)
        (let ((beg   (save-excursion (goto-char (region-beginning))
                                     (line-beginning-position)))
              (end   (save-excursion (goto-char (region-end)) (line-end-position))))
          
          (replace-string-in-region (car p) (cdr p) beg end))))))
```

It should turn something like:

`[1,2,3\\4,5,6\\7,8,9]` into

```latex
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9\\
\end{bmatrix}
```

I'm not seeing a lot of details on that error.

Comment: I suspect your code has the same bug as the code in [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74038/error-end-after-end-of-buffer-while-replacing-strings-in-a-region-inside-buf) question: as you are replacing, the end-of-buffer position changes, but you are using the same position and sometimes you end up pointing beyond the end of the buffer. If that answer fixes this problem, we can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: You would be better off building on what people already have bullt ... [LaTeX Input for Impatient Scholars](https://karthinks.com/software/latex-input-for-impatient-scholars/).  The second video in the article is captioned `Matrices in a hurry`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

There is/was a bug in the `replace-string-in-region` function.
Using the newest version of that function, your code works alright, except for some unwanted newlines due to the first backslash in the double backslash functioning as an escape character. To fix it, just replace the double backslashes `\\` by quadruple backslashes `\\\\`

END EDIT

It looks like you have encountered a bug in the `replace-string-in-region`.
If you closely look at the code of that function then you will find that the `end` argument passed to the `search-forward` function, does not move while the 'original region' expands (due to replacing a short string with a longer string).

Of course, I did not find this error by reading the source directly, but I was using [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Edebug.html) to investigate the behavior (I strongly advise you to read about edebug, as it is very simple to use, while it is a very powerful tool).

The error you are seeing seems to be triggered because, due to this bug, the position of `point` is after the position passed as `end` to the `search-forward` function.

I guess to make your code work, you would have to fix the `replace-string-in-region` to update the position passed as `end` to the `search-forward` function, or rewrite your algorithm otherwise.
Luckily, it looks like fixing that `replace-string-in-region` function should not be too difficult.

It would be great if subsequently you could contribute a patch with the fix (or otherwise create a bug report).

Comment: It looks like the `replace-string-in-region` function has been changed a few times in the last year(s), so I am not sure how exactly the version you are using looks like. I guess the explanation is relevant for most versions, but it would probably be wise to create the patch against the latest version (or just report the bug otherwise).

Comment: Actually, it looks like the function already has been fixed on 2022-09-11, so you should probably just obtain that fixed function from the latest Emacs source code.

Comment: It's probably *NOT* a `replace-string-in-region` bug: see my comment.

Comment: @NickD It probably really is a `replace-string-in-region`, as I have edebugged the function with a 'simple testcase', i.e. using `(replace-string-in-region "," " &" 1 22)` in a buffer containing only the 'example matrix', where the bug was easy to see. Furthermore (I forgot to mention), when simply using the latest version of that function, then the `latex-matrixify` function produces the correct result (except for some misplaced newlines). Finally, [here is a link](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=d8f392bccd46cdb238ec96964f220ffb9d81cc44) to the fix...

Comment: I could not easily find the bug report, but I have now found that it is just mentioned in that commit message. So finally [here](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2022-09/msg00951.html) also is the original bug report.

Comment: I must admit that I didn't try it out, so I could very well be wrong. I'll  have to take a look at the bug report and the fix and try it out in this particular case, but one thing that I just noticed that argues for @dalanicolai's point of view is that the error message in this case is different from the one in the question I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Calc. You can set `language mode` to `latex`, temporarily by opening a Calc session, or permanently by saving the configuration in the `calc.el` file.

Enable `calc-embedded` when the point is on this formula

```
 [1,2,3\\4,5,6\\7,8,9]
```

results in

```
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{pmatrix}
```

You must exit `calc-embedded-mode` to continue editing.

Just search and replace `pmatrix` with `bmatrix`.

A keyboard macro should do the job quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to write any `elisp`.

***The `name-last-kbd-macro` and `insert-kbd-macro` will write the `elisp` for you.***

1. `emacs -Q` **(`-Q` here is important)**
2. Copy the following to `*scratch*` buffer

```lisp
 [1,2,3\\4,5,6\\7,8,9]
```

3. Install the following snippet

```lisp
(defalias 'latex-matrixify
  (kbd
   "C-SPC C-M-f C-x n n ! C-SPC C-SPC 
<escape> < M-^ M-% [ <return> \\ b e g i n { b m a t r i x } C-q C-j <return> ! 
<escape> < M-% , <return> SPC & SPC <return> ! 
<escape> < M-% \\ \\ <return> \\ \\ C-q C-j <return> ! 
<escape> < M-% ] <return> C-q C-j \\ e n d { b m a t r x <backspace> i x } C-q C-j <return> ! 
<escape> < C-x n w"
   ))
```

3. Put the  cursor just before the `[` in the math fragment
4. Do `M-x latex-matrixify`

---

**`name-last-kbd-macro`** is an alias for `kmacro-name-last-macro` in
`loaddefs.el`.

```lisp
(`name-last-kbd-macro` `SYMBOL`)
```

***Assign a name to the last keyboard macro defined.***
Argument `SYMBOL` is the name to define.
The symbol`s function definition becomes the keyboard macro string.
Such a "function" cannot be called from Lisp, but it is a valid editor command.

---

**`insert-kbd-macro`** is an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in
`macros.el`.

```lisp
(`insert-kbd-macro` `MACRONAME` &optional `KEYS`)
```

***Insert in buffer the definition of kbd macro `MACRONAME`, as Lisp code.***
`MACRONAME` should be a symbol.
Optional second arg `KEYS` means also record the keys it is on
(this is the prefix argument, when calling interactively).

This Lisp code will, when executed, define the kbd macro with the same
definition it has now.  If you say to record the keys, the Lisp code
will also rebind those keys to the macro.  Only global key bindings
are recorded since executing this Lisp code always makes global
bindings.

To save a kbd macro, visit a file of Lisp code such as your `~/.emacs`, use this command, and then save the file.

Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 18.